# Idictionary as a source of SQL insert into

Tags: c#, sql, idictionary

I created Sql Update procedure using c# dynamic object ( here it is 'string,string' dictionary - 'sql_fields_name,value_to_insert' ) which works well.

```
public static string sp_UpdateDB(int ID, dynamic a, string procName, string connString)// update using stored procedures 
        {
    string resp=string.Empty;

    string conn_string = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(connString);
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_string))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procName, conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    // set id of updated record 
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int));
                    cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = ID;
                    // set all fields and values
                    var attribList = a.Keys;
                    foreach (var entry in attribList)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + entry, SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1));
                        cmd.Parameters["@" + entry].Value = (a[entry] == "") ? (object)System.DBNull.Value : a[entry];
                    }
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    resp += ex.Message;
                }
            }
            return resp;
        }
```

and Sql server procedure

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateDB] 
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
            @ID int = null 
            ,@JSON_Content nvarchar(max)= NULL 
            ,@number nvarchar(max)= NULL
            ,@email nvarchar(max)= NULL
            ,@first_name nvarchar(max)= NULL
            ,@JSON_changes nvarchar(max)= NULL
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        -- Insert statements for procedure here
        UPDATE [Intranet].[dbo].[Applications]
        SET
            [JSON_Content] = ISNULL(@JSON_Content ,[JSON_Content])
            ,[staff_number] = ISNULL(@staff_number ,[staff_number])
            ,[staff_email] = ISNULL(@staff_email ,[staff_email])
            ,[first_name] = ISNULL(@first_name ,[first_name])
            ,[JSON_changes] = ISNULL(@JSON_changes ,[JSON_changes])
        WHERE
            [ID]=@ID
END
```

Now, I would like to make the same with insert into and I am stuck. Can someone turn me to the right direction? I have got only c# version, I can't make it as a sql stored procedure.

Present code:

```
public static string insertDB(dynamic a, out int id, string tableName, string connString)
{
    string resp = "";
    string strSQL = "";
    id = 0;
    try
    {
        var attribList = a.Keys;
        string updateFields = "";
        string updateValues = "";
        foreach (var entry in attribList)
        {
            if (updateFields != "")
                updateFields += ",";
            if (updateValues != "")
                updateValues += ",";
            updateFields += "[" + entry + "]";
            updateValues += "'" + a[entry] + "'";
        }

        string conn_string = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(connString);
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_string);
        conn.Open();
        strSQL = "insert into " + tableName + " ( " + updateFields + " ) VALUES ( " + updateValues + " )";
        SqlCommand pushCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn);
        pushCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        pushCommand.CommandText = "Select @@Identity";  // get the just created record's ID
        id = System.Convert.ToInt32(pushCommand.ExecuteScalar());
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { resp += ex.ToString()+" id:"+id.ToString() + " " + strSQL; }
    return resp;
}
```

Comment: Are the values in `a` properly sanitized? If not, you are exposing yourself to SQL injection.

Comment: Absolutely should convert your insertDB procedure to use a parameterized statement, not a raw concatenated SQL string unless you have absolute, incontrovertible assurance those values are absolutely clean. Very risky.